# Movilizer - How to get the Answer of a Signature screen into the DC

Tags: mobile, electronic-signature, movilizer

How can i get the results of the Signature Screen into the cloud with a DataContainer. What formats are supported?

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first step is to call

```
binary getAnswerData(answer-descriptor answer)
```

or

```
binary getAnswerDataByClientKey(answer-descriptor answer, string clientKey)
```

This should give you the data. You can store it in a variable and add that to a data container. You have to take care not to store to much binary data in one single data container ... this will produce platform dependent problems. 1MB per data container should be safe on all platforms though. If you need to transmit more data, then chunk it into separate containers.

Answer (score 0):

> What formats are supported?

The captured image is returned in JPG-format.